# Attempting to post a file to the server during a submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

EDIT - It must run when the user submits, I would prefer to avoid an Ajax call if possible,

I'm having a problem sending a file to the server using the Javascript FormData object.  While posting everything here will obfuscate the issue and prompt a lot of 'why didn't you do this?' questions.

As part of my interface, a user drags and drops a file onto a part of the web page.  This prompts the following code to run:

```
var data = new FormData();
if (selectedFile != null) {
    data.append(selectedFile.name, selectedFile);
}
$('#myForm').submit();
```

The above code works correctly, other than the problem that I am having.  While the rest of the form is submitted properly, I am not getting the file I am trying to upload - I know this because I looked at the entirety of the network request, and it simply wasn't there.  There's no (obvious, at least) bug here, but there must be something that I am overlooking, forgetting, or simply don't know how to do.

FWIW, this is part of a drag and drop file submittal interface where for one reason or another the ones that I tried were not suitable.

Comment: `FormData` is used with AJAX. When you use `$('#myForm').submit()`, it just submits the form's fields, not any Javascript variables.

Comment: What library are you using for adding the file? (also what is `selectedFile` set to?)

Comment: @Barmar - Thanks, while it seems obvious to me now, your comment helped me clarify my thinking.  I figured I was missing something, but I was thinking/hoping that FormData would 'magically' add this in.  I will dump it into a form field before submittal.

Comment: @Petah - I'm just using e.dataTransfer.files[0], where e is the event data for a drop event listener on a DIV.  I'm positive that this is working properly, and that the FormData object doesn't connect at all to any form variables.

Comment: @EvConrad You could look into reading the file and submitting it as an encoded hidden input using `FileReader`: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38083/data-uri-encoder MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: @Petah I ended up doing pretty much this.  Thanks!